# Coordinate geometry - its 'other way round'.

Tags: soft-question

In coordinate geometry we solve the problems of geometry using techniques of algebra. What's the other way round? I mean to solve the problems of algebra (like proving the binomial theorem, etc.) using methods of geometry. Any suggestions please.

Comment: Slide rules? Nomograms?

Comment: Search for “Proof without Words”.